# Easiest way to install the Ionic android app I created on a mobile

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

On this website (https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/) I read that I should give this command on the command prompt: ionic cordova run android --prod --release

I tried it but it only tried to start the app on an emulator (I have some problems with it, so it didn't actually start the emulator). Does this command also create a file I can put on my mobile and install the app? I don't want to put the app on Google play, just on my mobile.

I tried putting the android-debug.apk on my mobile and running it but my mobile couldn't install it (.../platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk)

I'm not trying to test the app on my mobile, I'm trying to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deploy the apk to your device 
`ionic cordova run android --device` is indeed correct. (try adding `--device`)

You only need `--prod --release` when building for production (longer buildtime).

Before running (= building, installing and starting your app) check if your device has USB-debugging enabled. You can check if your device is connected by running `adb devices`. Since the `run` command includes building, yes `run` should create a apk for you.

As you said you also could install the apk manually. Here make sure to use the correct apk. *android-debug.apk* is the development build (no `--release` tag) and since your trying to run a production one (`--release`) you are looking for *android-release.apk* or *android-release-unsigned.apk*.

Answer (score 0):

go to settings -> security in your phone then check Unknown sources (Allow installation of apps from sources other than the play store) and try to put the android-debug.apk again. this should work